# Angular Firebase ngIf user is authenticated listener doesn't work on page reload

Tags: angular, firebase, observable, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I'm using onAuthStateChanged from firebase to listen to the authentication status of a user. I'm listening to those changes in my navigation component to decide whether to show a login button or a logout button etc..

This works fine if I'm navigating within the app, but when I refresh the page, the DOM reflect the state of the user even though the subscription gets fired.

Probably a simple fix that I'm overlooking, but I haven't been able to find a fix that works in my research and have put too much time into it -_- please help!

This is my authService:

```
  private authStatusSub = new Subject();
  user$ = this.authStatusSub.asObservable();

  setAuthStatusListener() {
    this.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.usersService
          .getUserData(user.uid)
          .then((userData) => {
            this.authStatusSub.next(userData);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      } else {
        this.authStatusSub.next(null);
        console.log('User has logged out');
      }
    });
  }
```

Navigation typescript file:

```
  isAuthenticated: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.setAuthStatusListener();
    this.authService.user$.subscribe((userData) => {
      if (userData) {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        console.log(userData);
      } else {
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Navigation html:

```
  <a routerLink="/login" *ngIf="!isAuthenticated" mat-button class="navButton">Login</a>
  <a mat-button *ngIf="isAuthenticated" class="navButton" (click)="onLogout()">Logout</a>
```

When I go through the normal app flow and login, logout, and navigate to the home page (where the nav bar sits), it works as expected, but when I refresh the home page (where the nav bar sits), the state isn't reflected in the DOM. Even though the state isn't reflected, the console.log() in the nav typescript file is fired with the correct data, so I know the observable is working.

Would deeply appreciate any help!!!

Comment: Maybe `authService.user$` emits before your subscription happens.  You could try using `ReplaySubject(1)` instead of plain Subject to ensure you get previously emitted value if subscription happens late.

Comment: In your `ngOnInit`, you could try to put the call to `this.authService.setAuthStatusListener();` at the end.

Comment: However, you it seems like you can greatly simplify your code since you are already using `AngularFireAuth` as it provides the `authState` as an observable already, so you won't need a subject.

Comment: I tried putting setAuthStatusListener() after subscribing with no luck :( I'm not familiar with ReplaySubject, I'll look it up

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't want to have any auth logic in any other components, but I suppose it's not any messier than how I'm doing it lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `AngularFireAuth`, you can simplify your service like this:

Service:

- get rid of Subject (`authStatusSub`)
- define `user$` directly from `AngularFireAuth.authState`
- don't subscribe in service!

So the code could look like this:

service:

```
constructor(private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

user$ = this.fireAuth.authState;
```

nav component:

```
this.authService.user$.subscribe(
    userData => this.isAuthenticated = !!userData
);
```